# Next-AuthV4 NextJS13 getSession() returns undefined

Tags: mysql, next.js13, next-auth

im trying to make an authentication for a project with credentials and i cant use prisma or any other adapter, i succeeded in making a registration that store the user on the database (i use mysql) and the login is also working as well, but when i log in i cant get the user info om my pages

i tried to log the session and get the user like this:

// dashboard/page.tsx

```
"use client";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

export default function page() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  console.log(session);

  return <div>teste</div>;
}
```

but i get that {session: undefied}, console:

```
{
    "user": {},
    "expires": "2024-03-23T14:10:55.102Z"
}
```

// server.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const cors = require("cors");
const db = require("./db");

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKPORT || 3010;
const secretKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_KEY;
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// Generate JWT token
const generateToken = (username) => {
  const token = jwt.sign({ username }, secretKey, {
    expiresIn: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
  });
  return token;
};

app.post("/auth/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    // Query database for user credentials
    const [rows] = await db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", [
      username,
    ]);

    if (rows.length === 0) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: "User not found" });
    }

    const user = rows[0];

    // Compare hashed password
    const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isPasswordValid) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid password" });
    }

    // Generate token
    const token = generateToken(username);

    console.log({
      user: {
        id: user.id_user,
        username: user.username,
        role: user.role,
      },
      accessToken: token,
    });

    // Return user information
    res.status(200).json({
      user: {
        id: user.id_user,
        username: user.username,
        role: user.role,
      },
      accessToken: token,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error authenticating user: ", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

app.post("/auth/signup", async (req, res) => {
  const { username, role, password } = req.body;

  try {
    // Check if username exists
    const [existingUsers] = await db.query(
      "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?",
      [username]
    );
    if (existingUsers.length > 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Username already exists" });
    }

    // Hash the password
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    await db.query(
      "INSERT INTO users (username, role, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
      [username, role, hashedPassword]
    );

    res.status(200).json({ message: "User registered sucessfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error registering user: ", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

// Start server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

// api/[...nextauth]/route.ts

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import type { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const backendURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKPORT;

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const credentialsDetails = {
          username: credentials?.username,
          password: credentials?.password,
        };

        const res = await fetch(`${backendURL}/auth/login`, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(credentialsDetails),
        });

        const user = await res.json();

        if (user) {
          return user;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET as string,
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }: any) {
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.user.id = token.id;
      return session;
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

// AuthProvider.tsx

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

type sessionProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

function AuthProvider({ children }: sessionProps) {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
}

export default AuthProvider;
```

// layout.tsx

```
import "./globals.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import AuthProvider from "@/utils/AuthProvider";
import Header from "@/components/Header";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const session = await getServerSession();
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <AuthProvider>
          <Header />
          {children}
        </AuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
```

// package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/next-auth": "^3.15.0",
    "@types/node": "20.11.16",
    "@types/react": "18.2.53",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.18",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.17",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "eslint": "8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.4",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.9.1",
    "next": "^13.5.6",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.6",
    "postcss": "8.4.35",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.4.1",
    "typescript": "5.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6"
  }
```

i'm also using a middleware according with the next-auth documentation.

i'm a begginner, so sorry is there's obvious erros